# How can I add Seam Security to my Netbeans Java EE 6 application?

Tags: jsf, seam, java-ee-6, cdi

I'm developing a web application using Java EE 6/JSF2/CDI with NetBeans and I want to use the Security Module of Seam to manage the authorization/authentication process.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, Seam3 is designed to add special sets of features to your basic Java EE application. So just check the [Seam Security](http://seamframework.org/Seam3/SecurityModule) documentation how to add certain features to your application.